# Session Value changes in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP page fbridge.php which sets a session value

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['type']="EMP";

?>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   window.location="index.php";

  </script>
```

The page then redirects to index.php which has the following code

```
<?
    echo "1=".$_SESSION['type'];
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['sessions_id']!=session_id())
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
    }
    echo "2=".$_SESSION['type'];
?>
```

**The problem is 1= is Always blank and 2=Always print some value that is not EMP.**

Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: some value? what is the value?

Comment: @FastSnail value=MNR which is set in some other page

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez shall I remove session_start from index.php?

Comment: `session_start();` should be BEFORE using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: enable error reporting.so you can see errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session_start() should be called before accessing or modifying session variables

FIRST:

```
   <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['type']="EMP";
        header("Location:index.php"); //This is better than javascript ?
    ?>
```

SECOND:

```
<?
    session_start();
    echo "1=".$_SESSION['type'];
    if($_SESSION['sessions_id']!=session_id()) 
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
        die("Browser doesn't support redirect"):
    }
    echo "2=".$_SESSION['type'];
?>
```

Comment: Well, this is something that google knows :) but anyways glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes session_start() is always before starting of script as you are accessing sessions. Because in HTTP request session values are sent inside header not on page's output. session_start() tells to access the session variables because HTTP is stateless protocol.